# What is the difference between Boy's Surface and tetra-hemi-hexahedron?

Tags: geometry

Our professor wants us to use the knowledge of the $\mathbb{RP^2}$ model in three dimensions containing self-intersection and/or singularities and real projective planes.

---

After Google (of course I can see they have different shape)

Only thing I can notice is Boy's surface, no matter which angle I look at it, it still in the same shape but not for tetra-hemi-hexahedron.

and one is an immersion and the other is not.

Our goal is to use more words less formula. Which is hard.

Comment: Do you know anything about the symmetry group of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? How many ways can you rotate each surface by a non-trivial amount so that the embedding is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that one is an immersion and the other is not already indicates they are different. Indeed, the singular locus for Boy's surface has a triple point plus a 1-manifold double point locus. For the tetra-hemi-hexahderon, there is a triple point, but the singular locus also has univalent vertices (this is where it fails to be an immersion), so the two maps of a projective plane into $\mathbb R^3$ are not equivalent.